# Liferay encoding after upgrade from 6.0.5 to 6.2

Tags: java, liferay-6

I have a problem with liferay character encoding after upgrading from 6.0.5 to 6.2
I have verified all of these files:
- Encoding in setenv.bat : -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
- Added the property in portal-ext.properties : file.encoding=UTF-8
- Added the filter in web.xml file :

```
<filter>
         <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
         <filter-class>
                   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
          </filter-class>
          <init-param>
                    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                   <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>force-encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is a screenshot of liferay portal:
[image]

**EDIT :**
Liferay version is 6.2 GA2 :
[image]

Comment: which *exact* version did you upgrade to? I'm assuming 6.2.5 GA6?

Comment: No, it's 6.2 GA2

Comment: Please use the latest available version for an upgrade: It also contain fixes for known issues with the upgrade routines. That's no guarantee that it'll work (I'm not aware of any problems messing with encoding) but it's the best bet. Plus, why upgrade to a version that already was fixed with a few later updates. (Note that 6.2.x won't get any more updates)

Comment: We need to upgrade to that version because we already have applications running under it. We've already done the upgrade but we didn't have encounter the encoding problem.